# Using isalnum with signed character inputs - Visual C++

Tags: c++

I have a very simple program where I am using the `isalnum` function to check if a string contains alpha-numeric characters. The code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    string test = "(…….";

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {     
            if (isalnum(test[i])) {
                cout << "True: " << test[i] << " " << (int)test[i] << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "False: " << isalnum(test[i]) << test[i] << " " << (int)test[i] << endl;
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Desktop Edition 2013 for this snippet. 
The issue(s):
1. When this program is run in Debug mode, the program fails with a debug assertion that says: "Expression c >= -1 && c <= 255"
Printing the character at the `ith` position results in a negative integer (-123). Converting all calls to isalnum to accept `unsigned char` as input causes the above error to disappear.

I checked the documentation for `isalnum` and it accepts arguments of type `char`. Then why does this code snippet fail? I am sure I am missing something trivial here but any help is welcome.

Comment: I would think that since you are using `_tmain` that this is an issue with Unicode.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @NathanOliver since the string clearly isn't a wide string it doesn't matter if the build is Unicode or not.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: `string` is `typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >
 string;`

Comment: @MarkRansom: Your right.  I was thinking basic_string which takes a charT.

Comment: Please update your question to show the `#include` directives. It could matter whether you're using the `isalnum` function defined in `<cctype>`, or the template function defined in `<locale>`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Updated the code. The version I am using is within <locale>.

Comment: You might still be using the `isalnum` declared in `<cctype>`. Headers can include other headers, and I'm not sure enough about C++ rules to be certain.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: @Sriram: Someone who knows C++ better than I do will have to answer that. It's entirely possible that I'm wrong.

Comment: Correction: You're definitely using the `isalnum` declared in `<cctype>`. See the answer I just posted. (I'm still not 100% sure of this, since I don't do a whole lot of C++; wait for the C++ experts to review what I wrote.)

Comment: @KeithThompson your answer is good

Answer (score 4):

The `isalnum` function is declared in `<cctype>` (the C++ version of `<ctype.h>`) -- which means you really should have `#include <cctype>` at the top of your source file. You're getting away with calling it without the `#include` directive because either `"stdafx.h"` or one of the standard headers (likely `<locale>`) includes it -- but it's a bad idea to depend on that.

`isalnum` and friends come from C. The `isalnum` function takes an argument of type `int`, which must be either within the range of `unsigned char` *or* equal to `EOF` (which is typically `-1`). If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

Annoyingly, this means that if plain `char` happens to be signed, passing a `char` value to `isalnum` causes undefined behavior if the value happens to be negative and not equal to `EOF`. The signedness of plain `char` is implementation-defined; it seems to be signed on most modern systems.

C++ adds a *template* function `isalnum` that takes an argument of any character type and a second argument of type `std::locale`.  Its declaration is:

```
template <class charT> bool isalnum (charT c, const locale& loc);
```

I'm fairly sure that this version of `isalnum` doesn't suffer from the same problem as the one in `<cctype>`. You can pass it a `char` value and it will handle it correctly. You can also pass it an argument of some wide character type like `wchar_t`. But it requires two arguments. Since you're only passing one argument to `isalnum()`, you're not using this version; you're using the `isalnum` declared in `<cctype>`.

If you want to use this version, you can pass the default locale as the second argument:

```
std::isalnum(test[i], std::locale())
```

Or, if you're sure you're only working with narrow characters (type `char`), you can cast the argument to `unsigned char`:

```
std::isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(test[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that characters are signed by default, and anything over 0x7f is being treated as a negative number when passed to `isalnum`. Make this simple change:

```
        if (isalnum((unsigned char)test[i])) {
```

Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k84c0490.aspx) clearly states that the parameter is `int`, not `char`. I believe you're getting confused with a [different version of `isalnum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w53whada.aspx) that comes from the `locale` header. I don't know why the function doesn't accept sign-extended negative numbers, but suspect that it's based on wording in the standard.

Comment: To be pedantic here, the signed-ness of `char`acters is implementation defined, not signed by default.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Changing the input to `unsigned char` does work, as I have indicated in my question. What I do not understand is that the function description for `isalnum` states that it accepts `charT` as input: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isalnum/. I am assuming the `charT` is the signed char. If that is true, then the straight call to `isalnum` should work too, right? No need to cast it to `unsigned char`?

Comment: @MarkB to be even more pedantic, the question is specifically about Visual Studio which absolutely defaults to signed.

Comment: `isalnum` et al should be avoided for anything which isn't ASCII [0-127]. Use a good Unicode library for anything which isn't ASCII.

Comment: @dalle that's good advice, but sometimes you don't have any control over your input. The function is very explicit about which characters it will return `true` for, so as long as you don't expect a `true` for anything outside of the ASCII range it should still be usable.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The `isalnum()` function declared in `<cctype>` pays attention to the current locale. In the default `"C"` locale, it returns true only for the 52 upper and lower case letters and the 10 digits.

Comment: @KeithThompson do you know if Microsoft's implementation produces `true` for characters other than the ones in the documentation if you specify a different locale? If so then the documentation is faulty - it wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No, I don't know. The standard says that it can return true for any member of a locale-specific set of characters (there are more details in the standard). That set may legally be empty.

Comment: The "why" is for historical reasons. The function is defined so that it can be implemented via lookup table, e.g. the implementation headers can have `extern char __isalnum_table[UCHAR_MAX];` and `#define isalnum(x) __isalnum_table[x]`.  However the standard also requires non-macro implementations to be available, so if you wrote `(isalnum)(x)` you have to get a function implementation, and I believe vendors typically wrote those to cope with negative values even though the standard doesn't require it.